# Split php string only after symbol

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Hi everybody i need some help,
im new in php. I have a string like this

```
$string="+note1-note2-note3+note4-note5-note6+note7-note8-note10";
```

I need to extract to array only the part with `+` like: `note1`, `note4`, `note7`.

Can someone help me?
Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with a regex.

```
$string="+note1-note2-note3+note4-note5-note6+note7-note8-note10";
preg_match_all('/\+(note\d+)/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => note1
    [1] => note4
    [2] => note7
)
```

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/pW3eS0/1

`\d` is a number and the second `+` is a quantifier meaning 1 or more of the preceding character/group. The first plus `\+` is literal, the preceding `\` makes it the actual `+` character, otherwise it would cause an error because it would be the quantifier but be quantifying nothing.

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/527661

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You are the best ;) 
With preg_match_all how can i access to single part of array? Like echo $array[0]; Thanks a lot!!

Comment: echo $matches[0][0]; ;)

Comment: Chris sorry i have another problem :(
If the string is $string="+dog-note2-note3+cat-note5-note6+fish-note8-note10";

How can i exctract only the pet with +??

Comment: Maybe something like, https://regex101.com/r/pW3eS0/2? Did you figure out echoing single values?