# php remove the word starts with #

Tags: php

I want to remove the words which are starts with # in the content.

For example

```
$content  = "#test Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry #test2 standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type #test3 and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. #test4 It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum #test5."
```

here #test1, #test2, #test3, #test4, #test5 are # words. I want to remove that words.

I use `preg_replace`. But its not getting output.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Post the code you used to try this.

Comment: This is probably pretty close, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711066/split-php-string-only-after-symbol/35711122#35711122 (swap `match_all` with `replace` and swap the `\+` with `#`. if not post what you currently have..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `/#[a-z0-9]+/i`. This pattern will replace any alphanumeric word followed by `#` with blank.

```
preg_replace('/#[a-z0-9]+/i', '', $content)
```

Comment: Don't need to escape the `#` and should add `i` modifier, or add in uppercase range.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks buddy. Updated.

Comment: It didn't replace the word which is last string.  i.e in the string "#EmpireKosher #Brooklyn #Supermarket #Kosher #WeeklySpecials #ShopKosher #KosherFood #CrownHeights"  It didn't replace the #CrownHeights     Because the last word doesn't contain the space after the word. How to fix this?

Comment: @Vasanthan.R.P Try the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `preg_replace('#.*?(?= |\.|,|!|\?)', '', $string);`

It will remove any string starting with `#`.